# Pandas groupby() on a multiindex dataframe when you need two columns in the apply() lambda

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a multi-index dataframe where I want to create a new column. In this new column, the value for all rows for that particular index should come from the value of the 'bin' column in the row where the 'type' is 'TX'. For example:

```
    From...
           type       bin
    id desc               
    1  a      TX  01110010
       a      RX  01110010
       b      TX  11110000
       b      RX  11110000
    2  a      RX  11101000
       b      TX  11110001
       b      RX  11110001

    What I want...
            type       bin    bin_tx
    id desc                         
    1  a      TX  01110010  01110010
       a      RX  00000010  01110010
       b      TX  11110000  11110000
       b      RX  11110000  11110000
    2  a      RX  11101000          
       b      TX  00110001  00110001
       b      RX  11110001  00110001

    What I get...
            type       bin bin_tx
    id desc                      
    1  a      TX  01110010    NaN
       a      RX  01110010    NaN
       b      TX  11110000    NaN
       b      RX  11110000    NaN
    2  a      RX  11101000    NaN
       b      TX  11110001    NaN
       b      RX  11110001    NaN
```

My issue is that when I try to use apply() on the groupby, the column 'bin_tx' comes back as NaN for all rows. I assume this has something to do with pandas not knowing how to deal with the different indices between the groupby and the original df?

However, if I try to use transform(), this of course processes the columns one at a time - i.e. I can't get the value from the 'bin' column

MWE:

```
    d1 = {'id': ['1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '2', '2'],
          'desc': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
          'type': ['TX', 'RX', 'RX', 'TX', 'RX', 'TX', 'RX'],
          'bin': ['01110010', '01110010', '11101000', '11110000', '11110000', '11110001', '11110001']}
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
    print(df1)
    df1.set_index(['id', 'desc'], inplace=True, drop=True)
    df1.sort_index(inplace=True)

    d2 = {'id': ['1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '2', '2'],
          'desc': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
          'type': ['TX', 'RX', 'RX', 'TX', 'RX', 'TX', 'RX'],
          'bin': ['01110010', '00000010', '11101000', '11110000', '11110000', '00110001', '11110001'],
          'bin_tx': ['01110010', '01110010', '', '11110000', '11110000', '00110001', '00110001']}
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
    print(df2)
    df2.set_index(['id', 'desc'], inplace=True, drop=True)
    df2.sort_index(inplace=True)

    df3 = df1.copy()
    df3['bin_tx'] = 

    df3.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.bin.values[0] if (x.type == 'TX').any() else '')
    print("\nFrom...")
    print(df1)
    print("\nWhat I want...")
    print(df2)
    print("\nWhat I get...")
    print(df3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your code

```
s=df3.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda x: x.bin.values[0] if (x.type == 'TX').any() else '')
out=df3.join(s.to_frame('binTX'),how='left')
        type       bin     binTX
id desc                         
1  a      TX  01110010  01110010
   a      RX  01110010  01110010
   b      TX  11110000  11110000
   b      RX  11110000  11110000
2  a      RX  11101000          
   b      TX  11110001  11110001
   b      RX  11110001  11110001
```

Comment: Please explain your code (which you tend not to do in some but not all of your [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7964527/yoben-s?tab=answers) (i.e., `IIUC...`)), like *how* did you fix OP's code.